# (GWT) - Why doesn't my call to TableSectionElement.setInnerSafeHtml() get rendered to the DOM?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a legacy application that uses UIBinder to render the UI. I am trying to spit out records into a standard  element. In my view.ui.xml file, I have a table with my semantic  element setup and a  element with the appropriate ui:field.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Customer #</th>
      <!-- Shortened for brevity -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ui:field="tbody"><!-- Note the ui:field defined -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In my view.java class, I have that ui:field coupled to a TableSectionElement.

```
public class View extends Composite implements ViewPresenterInterface {
    @UiField TableSectionElement tbody;
    public TableSectionElement getTbody() {
      return tbody;
    }
}
```

In my class that handles rendering the table elements, the code is fairly straight-forward:

```
private void renderOrderTable() {
        List<OrderToReviewProxy> sortedList = sortOrders(orders);
        SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        for(OrderToReviewProxy order : sortedList) {            
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<tr>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<td>");
            sb.appendEscaped(order.getCustomerNumber());
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("</td>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("</tr>");
        }
        view.getTbody().setInnerHTML(""); // Breakpoint A

        view.getTbody().setInnerSafeHtml(sb.toSafeHtml()); // Breakpoint B
    }
```

At Breakpoint A, inspecting view.getTbody() shows me the <tbody></tbody> element empty, as expected.
Stepping over Breakpoint B, inspecting view.getTbody() shows me the <tbody> element with the expected HTML that the SafeHtmlBuilder generated during the for loop.

However, when I look at the rendered page, the <tbody> element has no child nodes. None of the HTML from calling sb.toSafeHtml() seems to get written into the DOM. Can anyone help me out here? I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Can you show us how do you add your view to the DOM?

Comment: It's included in another view.ui.xml file using an xmlns (oa) to refer to the proper class. <oa:OrderAdminView ui:field="oaView" />. When that outer view is initialized, I grab the instance of the view with the issue and fire off its init...like so this.desktopView.getViewPagePresenter().ViewPresenter();

Comment: Thank you @Adam! Your comment made me realize the problem was how I was referring to the view from the container. It was a separate instances that was not the one actually attached to the DOM. You are awesome!

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)